# Validar se usuário está logado e redirecionar para a página que estava tentando acessar

Tags: php

Olá,

Estou com a seguinte dúvida. Quando o usuário acessa a página: /carteirinha, há uma validação para saber se ele está logado, caso não esteja, ele é redirecionado para a página de login, porém, após o login ele cai na página inicial. Teria como redirecionar para a página: /carteirinha, pois ele tentou acessar lá primeiro?

Segue o código que vai no cabeçalho e valida o usuário:

```
<?php

  define ( "_WOJO" , true );
  require_once ( "../init.php" );

  if ( ! App :: Auth () -> is_User ())
     Url :: redirect (SITEURL .  '/' );

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode obter a origem do usuário utilizando "[filter_input](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php)" com a variável **HTTP_REFERER**.

No arquivo de validação de login, tente algo como:

```
$origem = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_REFERER');
$destino = "https://dominio.com/login";

if (!is_null($origem)) {
   $destino = $origem; // ex. /carteirinha
}

header('Location: ' . $destino, true, 302);
```

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigado.